# Intersect function stops working after the first intersect

Tags: java, vector, processing, intersection, intersect

im making a game, but i ran into a problem while working with the function "intersect". 
the senario looks like this; i've made a game where the player is a rectangle were the objective is to kill the enemy rectangle. The enemy "boss" rectangle has two "simulations" that simulate a movement and an attack these simulations are driven by vectors. The movement is horizantally back and forth and the attack is in a vertical maner, a charge type of deal. The boss also has a rectangular target area where if itersected the "boss" will charge across the screen.
now the problem comes when i tried to make it so that if the player intersects with the rectangular target area the "boss" will attack/charge. The boss attack/charge the first time the player intersects but not after that. I want the boss to follow the same pantern, is that he should only be able to go from side to side horizantaly and if Target area intersected; attack/charge verticaly.

( i will include some code bellow. sorry if my english is bad. ) 
first comes the main:

```
boss b;
Character C;

void setup(){
C = new Character();
b = new boss();
}

void draw(){
if (play) {
    b.simulate();    //horizantal movement
}

if (b.start) {
    b.sim();             //boss vertical attack
}
if (b.intersects(C)){

    play = false;
    b.start = true;
}
C.character();             //player
b.bounce();               //makes it bounce if horizantal. and stop if vertical
b.Display();              //boss
b.display();             //boss target area
}
```

Next comes the boss:

```
class boss {
int x = 10 ;
int y = 10 ;
boolean start = false;
int RW = 50;
int RH = 700;
boolean up = false;
boolean down = true;

boss() {

  Location = new PVector( x+25, y );   //vector for the location of the boss
  Velocity = new PVector( 5, 0 );      // vector for horizaltal movement
  speed = new PVector( 0, 10 );        // vector for vertical down movement
  speed2 = new PVector(0, -10);       // vector for vertical up movement
}
void bounce() {
  if ((Location.x == width) ||(Location.x == 0)) {   //horizantal movement bounce on screen edge
    Velocity.x = Velocity.x * -1;

}
if ((Location.y == 650) || (Location.y == 0)) {
  start = false;                            //makes boss stop if reaches botton or top of the screen
  play = true;
  if (Location.y == 650) {                   
    RH = -700;
    up = true;
    down = false;      //specificly if it reaches top of screen
  }
  if (Location.y == 0) {
    RH = 700;                               
    down = true;       //specificly if it reaches bottom of screen
    up = false;
  }
  }
  }
void simulate() {
  Location.add(Velocity);    //simulates horizantal movement
}
void sim() {
  if (down) {
    Location.add(speed);      //simulates up and down attacking movemnet
  }
  if (up) {
  Location.add(speed2);
  }
}
boolean intersects(Character C) {

  return  Location.x < C.x + C.w && C.x < Location.x + RW && 
  Location.y < C.y + C.h && C.y < Location.y + RH; //intersect between player and boss targeting area

}
void Display() {
  rect( Location.x, Location.y, 50, 50 );   //boss
}
void display() {
  rect( Location.x, Location.y+50, RW, RH );   //boss targeting area

}

}
```

if anything is unclear i will gladly clear up any confusion. :)

Comment: Do you have this code on github or some place I could download and debug it on my laptop?

Comment: I have uploaded the zip file to my github. in repositories. here is the link: https://github.com/Greezy-Giga-Bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code. It made it much easier.

When I comment this piece (not the if-condition the reset of `start` after the if)

`if ((Location.y == 650) || (Location.y == 0)) {
  // start = false;`

then the boss starts going back up top and still calls intersects the Character when the co-ordinates match. However, post this the boss keeps bouncing up and down.

There is surely more work to be done on this to take account of the bullets fired and the hits to boss.

Hope this helps. :)  It was fun debugging this code. I had never used PDE before this.

ok, here is the "edit".. 
Now,

**Good News:** I can make it go in both directions only when it intersects

**Bad News:** It keeps going to the other side as long as it is intersecting. So if the `Character` is stationary then `boss` keeps intersecting and passing to the other side at least 8-10 times in the current speed.

Anyways, here is the summary. I added and `isAttacking` flag that tells the program to not stop the boss from crossing over if it has reached the bottom of the frame. The other thing I changed was the intersection condition. Now it just checks for intersection on the X-Axis. If you must compare intersection on the Y-Axis too then `intersects` is where you need to change & test.

After the long explanation :P Here is the code. Hope this is better.

**Main**

```
boss b;
Character C;
Inventory I;
Bullet B;
int previousKey = 0;
int lastKey;
int lastKeyCode;



void setup() {

  C = new Character();
  b = new boss();
  I = new Inventory();
  background(128, 128, 128);
  size( 700, 700 );
  strokeWeight( 10 );
  frameRate( 30 );
}
void keyPressed() {

  if (key == CODED) {
    previousKey = keyCode;
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      C.MoveUP();
    }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      C.MoveLEFT();
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      C.MoveDOWN();
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      C.MoveRIGHT();
    }
  }

  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
    attack();
  }
  if ( key == 'q' || key == 'Q' ) {
    if (I.Shoot == true) {
      B = new Bullet(C.x, C.y);
      this.Shoot();
    }
  } else if (key == 'e' || key == 'E') {
    I.changePop();
  }
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
      //play = false;
      //b.start = true;
    }
  }
}


void attack() {
  if (I.Attack == true) {
    if (previousKey == UP) {
      C.AttackUP();
    }
    if (previousKey == LEFT) {
      C.AttackLEFT();
    }
    if (previousKey == DOWN) {
      C.AttackDOWN();
    }
    if (previousKey == RIGHT) {
      C.AttackRIGHT();
    }
  }
}
void Shoot() {

  if (I.Shoot == true) {
    if (previousKey == UP) {
      B.ShootUP();
    }
    if (previousKey == LEFT) {
      B.ShootLEFT();
    }
    if (previousKey == DOWN) {
      B.ShootDOWN();
    }
    if (previousKey == RIGHT) {
      B.ShootRIGHT();
    }
  }
}

boolean play = true;
void keyReleased() {
  lastKey = 0;
  lastKeyCode = 0;
}

void draw() {
  background(128, 128, 128);


  if (play) {
    b.simulate();//side to side
  }

  if (b.start) {
    b.sim();      //boss rush
  }
  if (b.intersects(C)) {
    b.isAttacking = true;
    play = false;
    b.start = true;
  } else {
    b.isAttacking= false;
  }
  C.character();
  b.bounce();
  b.Display();//boss
  b.display();//rush area
  C.HPbar();
  I.popUp();
  if ( key == 'q' || key == 'Q' ) {
    if (I.Shoot == true) {
      B.bullet();
      B.Simulate();
    }
  }
}
```

**Enemies** or **Boss**

```
class boss {
  PVector Location;
  PVector Velocity;
  PVector speed;
  PVector speed2;
  int x = 10 ;
  int y = 10 ;
  boolean start = false;
  int RW = 50;
  int RH = 700;
  boolean up = false;
  boolean down = true;

  boolean isAttacking = false;

  boss() {

    Location = new PVector( x+25, y );
    Velocity = new PVector( 5, 0 );
    speed = new PVector( 0, 10 );
    speed2 = new PVector(0, -10);
  }
  void bounce() {
    if ((Location.x == width) ||(Location.x == 0)) {
      Velocity.x = Velocity.x * -1;
    }
    if ((Location.y == 650) || (Location.y == 0)) {
      if (!isAttacking) {
        start = false;
      }
      play = true;
      if (Location.y == 650) {
        RH = -700;
        up = true;
        down = false;
      }
      if (Location.y == 0) {
        RH = 700;
        down = true;
        up = false;
      }
    }
  }

  void simulate() {

    Location.add(Velocity);
  }
  void sim() {
    //print("\n In Sim UP: [" + up + "] Down: [" + down + "] Location [" + Location + "]");
    if (down) {
      Location.add(speed);
    }
    if (up) {
      Location.add(speed2);
    }
  }





  boolean intersects(Character C) {
    //print ("\nUP: [" + up + "] Down: [" + down + "] X: [" + (Location.x < (C.x + C.w) && (Location.x + RW) > C.x) 
    //+ "] Y: [" + (Location.y < (C.y + C.h) && (Location.y + RH) > C.y) + "]");

    return  Location.x < (C.x + C.w) && (Location.x + RW) > C.x;  
    //&& 
    //  Location.y < (C.y + C.h) && (Location.y + RH) > C.y ;
  }



  void Display() {
    pushStyle();
    stroke(0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect( Location.x, Location.y, 50, 50 );

    popStyle();
  }
  void display() {
    pushStyle();
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(0);
    fill(255, 0, 0, 20);
    rect( Location.x, Location.y+50, RW, RH );
    popStyle();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for helping. But i've might have worded my question wrong. I dont want the boss to bounce around "freely", if you know what i mean. I want the boss to follow the same system. if not intersected; go side to side horizantaly. if intersected go to the oposite side of the screen. And not start bouncing around.

Comment: @TheBigChung Please update your post with the right informations/questions, AG did a good job debugging but he might not want to do this several times.

Comment: Ok, apologies. I have updated the question to fit the problem better.

Comment: @TheBigChung does the last edit do close to what you wanted it to do?

Comment: It worked out very well. I changed it a tad bit tho, i put "play = true;" inside of "if(!isAttacking){"and it worked just as intended. So mabey.  Thx alot brother.